# How to return List value from controller to view using linq in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have created two tables:

```
TABLE 1: MainMenu
Fields: ParentID,MainMenu,Status
TABLE 2 : SubMenu
Fields: ChildId,ParentID,SubMnu,Status
```

How to return LIST value from controller to view page?

In class File:

[image]

In controller:

[image]

View Page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

View should be

```
@model IEnumerable<LIMS.Models.NavigationMenu>
```